# How to detect clicked links in CefSharp 3

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I recently updated from CefSharp `1.25.7` to the most recent (`39.0.0-pre02`) in the hopes that it would be easier to detect when a link is clicked. In `1.25.7` there was a navigation type but that was very unreliable and even directly clicking links would just count as "other" instead of "link clicked".

Basically my use case is that I have a hosted "start page" in my application that has many links. I would like to let the user open those links in their external browser, which isn't hard other than the fact that I don't know what is a link click and what is the page just navigating around. Most of our users (myself included) will have firewalls so when they open the first time it will redirect a bunch. Unfortunately some of those redirections and navigations have transition type of "LinkClicked" for some reason so I can't just check that in the `IRequest` in `OnBeforeBrowse`. Any ideas how I could tell that a link was *actually* clicked so I know to direct it to the system to open in their default browser?

Comment: Are you positively sure that the source of those "false LinkClicked" transition types is your firewall, and e.g. not some pages with frames in them? If the firewall is injecting something false it might be hard to detect. Note, we just got an incoming issue, or rather a question, related to [`OnBeforeBrowse`](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/829). Maybe relevant for you?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I enter in my username and password and submit them. The transition type on that is FormSubmitted, as expected. Then it redirects a few times while authenticating. A few of those steps show up as "Other" while a few show up as "LinkClicked" The only click I do from start to finish is submitting the form.

Comment: I recently updated to the most recent CefSharp3 (39.0.2) and I'm still seeing all sorts of odd behavior. For example, when loading an embedded flash video, the transition type is "LinkClicked" for all sorts of file loading. And I didn't even click any links for the firewall here.
I really just want to detect if the user clicks a link to open a window and direct that to open using the system browser instead of another popup CefSharp window (nothing against CefSharp, I just think users would like to use their local browser/settings to log into things like linkedin and other member sites).